# Issue with Promise not getting resolved with maximum retries attempt

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

I am struggling for past couple of days with Promise and a beginner. I have to call an external API and check if response is there or not. If null then call api again with maximum retry attempts, that is configurable. I tried the following, but not sure what I am missing here. Here is a sample what I did.

If data is available then show data is available. If not then retry for some time and if reaches zero then resolve with data not availabe in API. If data is available after some retry (for eg: 2nd time) then stop and show response.

```
function callExternalAPI(retry, interval) {
 try {
    return new promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if(retry <=0 ) {
            return resolve("Data not available in API"); // This is not working, request is hanged.
        }
        return myapiCall().then((response) => {
           if(!response) {
              // If empty then retry calling api again
              return setTimeOut(async () => {
                 await callExternalAPI(retry - 1, interval)
              }, interval);
           }
           return resolve(response);
        })
    })
}
   } catch((error) => {
       reject(error);
    })



callExternalAPI(3, 1000).then((rsp) => {
   console.log({response: "data available"});
}).catch((error) => {
  throw error;
})
```

Any help would be really appreciated as I am still on the learning phase.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Not sure but in myapicall callback you are using response as variable name and you are checking if(!result), so just make sure both are same.

Comment: @RajShah It is a typo when asked in S.O.

Comment: If you are a beginner with Promises as written in you post  you may find these few tutorial very helpful: https://tutorama.info/CTG/Promises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to wrap the "waiting" between tries into a separate `async` method and `await` this method.

Then, simply recur `callExternalApi` if no successful result has been returned from `myapiCall` as long as the retry-count has not reached `0`. Note that in my example I'm throwing an error if we've reached the max count (you can handle this differently of course like returning `undefined/null`):

```
async function wait(timeInMs) {
  console.log('Waiting ...');
  return new Promise((resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(), timeInMs)));
}


async function callExternalApi(numberOfTries, timeout) {
  if (numberOfTries <= 0) {
    return "Data not available in API";
  }

  const result = await myapiCall();

  if (result) {
    return result;
  }

  await wait(timeout); // wait for the defined timeout before recurring

  return callExternalApi(numberOfTries - 1, timeout);
}

(async () => {
   try {
     const result = await callExternalApi(3, 1000);
     console.log(result);
   } catch(err) {
     console.log(err);
   }
})();
```

Comment: If reached max retries then I need to return something like "data not available " and  donot want to throw.

Comment: @Vishnu: Fixed it, please check again.

Comment: Sure i will try, just eager about how we can implement the same in Promise. :)

Comment: @Vishnu: if it's for learning purposes it's fine, for production code you should definitely go with async/await as it allows for much clearer code as you can see in my example.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the [async / await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) syntax, this allows us to structure the code in a more understandable form, once we do this, it's relatively straightforward to create a wrapper function, callExternalAPI to loop over the API call.

The wait function is called after each failure, you could make this more sophisticated, perhaps backing off for a longer amount of time for each attempt, but we'll leave a constant interval for now.

```js
// Let's make this fail on the first couple of calls.
let myApiCallCount = 0;

// Mock function to simulate an API call. You can replace this with a real api call.
function myapiCall() {
    if (++myApiCallCount < 3) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(reject, 500, new Error("Some API error")));
    }
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500, { users: [ { name: "user1"},{ name: "user"} ]}));
}

function wait(interval) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, interval));
}

async function callExternalAPI(apiFunction, attemptCount, interval) { 
    for(let attempt = 1; attempt <= attemptCount; attempt++) { 
        console.log(`callExternalAPI: Calling ${apiFunction.name}, attempt ${attempt} of ${attemptCount}`);
        try {
            let response = await apiFunction();
            // Check if response is null.
            if (response) {
                console.log(`callExternalAPI: Success: Received response: ${JSON.stringify(response)}, exiting loop...`);
                return response;
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(`callExternalAPI: Error occurred: ${error}`);
        }
        // Wait for <interval> milliseconds.
        await wait(interval);
    }
    return null;
}

callExternalAPI(myapiCall, 3, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Some remarks about your code.
Your try catch is not implemented properly and the code won't execute.
You are not checking if there is a `response` because you used `result` instead
in this line `myapiCall().then((response) => { if(!result) ...` it should be `myapiCall().then((response) => {if(!response)`, although you should be careful when checking api response because `fetch` for example doesn't handle errors so in that case you should check the response status `response.status==200`,otherwise it will always default to true, also in your example you don't need to use setTimeout, you can just check for a response and if there is no response you call the function again.
Optimising your code i believe it should look something like this

```
    i=0
function callExternalAPI(retry, interval) {
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         return myapiCall().then((response) => {
           if (response) return response  //if you are using fetch / axios....... use response.status==200
            if(!response) {   //if you are using fetch / axios .... use response.status!=200
                    while(i<retry){
                      setTimeout(async()=>{
                        retry--
                   return await callExternalAPI(retry,interval)  
                      },interval)
                        i++              
                    }
                  if(i>retry) console.log("Data Not Available From This Api")
            }
         })
     })
 }
 callExternalAPI(3, 1000).then((rsp) => {
    console.log(rsp);
 }).catch((error) => { 
   throw error;
 })
```

Comment: @sven-hig: Thanks for your feedback. The thing is i have to call api specific number of times. ie; if customer give input as 3, then max retry attempt will be 3, if result is null. This is why i have used setTimeout. Please feel free to comment.

Comment: I Have updated the code to take that into account, try it and see if it works for you

Comment: @sven-hig Do we need else case when response is null? Becuase we are already checking in the code whether response is there or not. correct me i f i am wrong.

Comment: if you mean by response is null an empty object, no you don't have to as it's considered as a successful response,  you can probably show a message to the client "No data available", I have modified the code a bit and tested as well it should work, check it out and let me know if it works for you, any more questions feel free to ask

Comment: @sven-hig Yes i meant both if(response) & else return response are doing the same thing right? so it is redundanct.

Comment: the first response is when you make the first api call, and then if it is not successful it goes into a loop and that has 2 outcomes either you get a response and then your resolve that that's where the else comes to play or you show a msg "No data ....."

Comment: Acutally you are correct, I have looked at the code again there is no need for the `else`

Answer (score 0):

At the point where `return setTimeOut()` appears, you need to be returning a Promise ..... which `setTimeOut()` does not provide.

The knack lies in knowing how to "promisify" `setTimeOut()`

```
function delay(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, ms);
    });
}
```

With `delay()` in place, you can write:

```
function callExternalAPI(retry, interval) {
    return myapiCall()
    .then(response => {
        if(response) {
            return response; // Yay!
        } else {
            throw new Error('response was falsy'); // Doh!
        }
    })
    .catch((error) => { // here, catch error arising async failure of myapiCall() or from response being falsy.
        if(retry <= 0) {
            throw error; // when retries run out, rethrow last error
        } else {
            return delay(interval) // here, benefit from the promisification of setTimeout().
            .then(() => callExternalAPI(retry - 1, interval));
        }
    });
}
```